# as.formula in R doesn't seem to accept a name that starts with a number followed by _

Tags: r, formula

How can I avoid getting the following error. The as.formula() does not seem to take a variable starting with a number and followed by `_` (underscore).  I am generating these variables dynamically and I am at a stage where I do not want to go back and change the variable names.
Thanks

```
lhsOfFormula = "25_dep"
rhsOfFormula  = "predVar1+predVar2+10_predVar3"
as.formula(paste(lhsOfFormula , " ~ ", rhsOfFormula ))
```

ERROR:

```
> as.formula(paste(lhsOfFormula , " ~ ", rhsOfFormula ))
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:3: unexpected input
1: 25_
     ^
```

Comment: That's not a valid variable name in R. See `?make.names`. The solution is probably to go back and change all your variable names to ones that are syntactically valid.

Comment: It really shouldn't be all that hard to run a grep-ish script to change all your names to something syntactically valid.  It's really a bad idea to have variable names which begin with numerals in **any** language .  There are some languages, for example, which interpret `37bongo` as `37*bongo` .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap the names in backticks, something like this

```
> lhsOfFormula <- "25_dep"
> rhsOfFormula <- c("predVar1", "predVar2", "10_predVar3")
> addq <- function(x) paste0("`", x, "`")
> as.formula(paste(addq(lhsOfFormula) , " ~ ", paste(addq(rhsOfFormula),collapse=" + " )))
`25_dep` ~ predVar1 + predVar2 + `10_predVar3`
```

I also vaguely remember there's a function to help with creating formulas, something like `formulate`, maybe? But I can't find anything about it in my quick search.

EDIT: Thanks to @DWin, it's `reformulate`, which helps with the response but not with the predictors.  Here the RHS is changed to have a valid name so that the code works:

```
> lhsOfFormula = "25_dep"
> rhsOfFormula  = c("predVar1", "predVar2", "x10_predVar3")
> reformulate(rhsOfFormula, lhsOfFormula)
`25_dep` ~ predVar1 + predVar2 + x10_predVar3
```

EDIT: Applying formula directly to a data frame will add the backticks automatically, using the first column as the response

```
> d <- data.frame(`25_dep`=1:5, predvar1=1:5, predvar2=1:5, `10_predvar3`=1:5, 
                  check.names=FALSE)
> formula(d)
`25_dep` ~ predvar1 + predvar2 + `10_predvar3`
```

The code for that function (`stats:::formula.data.frame`) can be adapted; it uses `as.name` like this:

```
> lhsOfFormula <- "25_dep"
> rhsOfFormula <- c("predVar1", "predVar2", "10_predVar3")
> ns <- sapply(c(lhsOfFormula, rhsOfFormula), as.name)
> formula(paste(ns[1], paste(ns[-1], collapse="+"), sep=" ~ "))
`25_dep` ~ predVar1 + predVar2 + `10_predVar3`
```

Comment: @DWin: That's the one.  It only helps with the response, though.

Comment: @learner: Glad to hear it.  Be sure to read the warning in the help for `formula` about using non-standard names. (Briefly, they may not work with all functions that use formulas.)

Comment: @DWin: `update` doesn't seem to add the necessary backticks, though.

Comment: `update` wouldn't automatically add them, but it seems to gracefully accept an argument with backticks.